# Removes the last two digits of a positive integer base 10 number that is greater than 99 in java

Tags: java, integer

My homework question is :Removes the last two digits of a positive integer base 10 number that is greater than 99

```
 * @param n
 *            a positive integer number greater than 99
 * @return the integer produced by removing the last two digits of n
```

my code is:

```
 public static int removeLastTwoDigits(int n) {
        int m = 0;
        String sn = Integer.toString(m);
        if(n>99 ) {
            String result = sn.substring(0, sn.length() - 1);
            m = Integer.parseInt(result);
        }
        return m;
    }
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Is your question how to change `1` to `2`?

Comment: Why not divide by 100?

Comment: Include an example of sample input and expected output.

Comment: Why are you returning `m` when `n <= 99`?

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 2):

```
 public static int removeLastTwoDigits(int n) {
     return n / 100;
 }
```

Comment: Forgot these were integers now